# Why do most flags get closed quickly, but some linger?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags

I'm fairly new to contributing, but I've been trying to flag questions that are obviously off-topic when I see them.  Most of my flags get responded to almost immediately, but it seems like some linger for a long time, and I'm just kind of curious why.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407668/extended-monitor-modelfy1650-is-not-working

It's clearly off topic, I voted it as off-topic, but it's still active almost a month after my flag.  It's not a big deal, I'm just curious why.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that your flag goes into the Close Vote queue to be reviewed, and there's ~120K questions in that queue. So it'll take a while.

Comment: That flag causes it to show up in a review queue. And that queue currently has >120k items in it.

Comment: So I understand that there's 120k questions in there, but why do some go really fast, and some take a month?  I guess that's where my confusion comes from.

Comment: Well, I think the reason it took so long to be reviewed is that it wasn't seen by pretty much anyone outside of the queue. It only has 22 views, and only has an obscure tag, [tag:dual-monitor].

Comment: If you write a custom flag, or flag NAA it goes to a smaller queue that moderators see. If you flag it spam or offensive it goes into that queue with a red icon.

Comment: And... it's closed now. The meta effect. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For close votes (which are different from other kinds of flags in that they're almost exclusively *not* handled by mods unless they're spam), a lot of it has to do with the tag they're in.  If there is an off topic question in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), it might survive simply because it heads to the bottom of the list quickly; but in a tag that gets 10ish new questions a day and has 50-100 people reading it, odds are a clearly OT question will be closed quickly.

In [sas](/questions/tagged/sas), though, we don't have 5 regular readers of 3k+ reputation (enough to cast close votes and see them); so sometimes obviously needing closing questions survive for a while until they come up in the close vote queue often enough (infrequently now that there are 120k questions in it).

Also, questions by new users are more likely closed quickly, because they also show up in the First Posts queue.

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you for your answer! I'll accept shortly.

Comment: I was wondering this myself. Two days ago I flagged four posts. Two were marked helpful in ~15 minutes. The other two are still listed as active.